# Can we integrate Telr Payment Gateway with React Native?

Tags: react-native, payment-gateway, 2checkout, payfort, telr

I am building a react-native app for a service provider and i am looking for possible payment gateway modules for payment integrations. So far I have narrowed down to two: 2checkout, Payfort and Telr. But I am not able to find any relevant implementations for React Native. Since the app is to be used in UAE, there's a very few gateways that I can use. Any help in this matter is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Foloosi**
Foloosi Technology, a payment gateway UAE brings to you easy to use options that are designed to be accessible, convenient and simple backed by reputed partners to provide security and a credible and reliable customer experience.
Foloosi Technology, online payment gateway UAE provides a convenient way for a user to make in – store payments and can be used at business listed with the Foloosi Technology service provider.

click for Foloosi:  [ReactNative package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-foloosi-widget?activeTab=readme)

**PayFort**
Payfort is a standout amongst the most broadly utilized payment gateways doors in UAE district. They as of late changed their valuing plans. Presently Payfort is just offering two valuing choices starter and Enterprise. For starter bundle, the month to month expense is 420 AED while for every exchange they charge 2.94 + 1.84 AED. Endeavor bundle is specially put together which depends with respect to the size of your business.
With the coordinated effort of Shop in Dubai (Now possessed by Amazon), an online web based business monster in UAE, PayFort has likewise propelled their Card-On-Delivery(COD) administration. Fundamentally, Card-on-conveyance implies that payment gateways on-conveyance clients will currently have a decision of paying with money or via card. The conveyance operators can process all significant credit and charge cards utilizing a versatile card machine.

click for PayFort: [ReactNative package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-payfort)

**PayTabs**
A Bahrain based specialist co-op which beat the rundown of best business new companies In 2016 aggregated by Forbes.They are putting forth their administrations in 168 monetary standards. You can set up total PayTabs framework in under 24 hours. There is various ways you can incorporate PayTabs like Plug-in, iFrame, SDK or direct joining by utilization of API. At present, they are charging 2.85 % + 1 AED per exchange.
The setup cost is $400 while every withdrawal costs up to $15. Paytabs isn’t charging any month to month or yearly support expense.

click for PayTab: [ReactNative package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-paytabs)

content referred by quora